# why i am getting force close when i want to exit?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

is there another code for exit the app?
i dont know why it doesnt working in here it worked for me all the time.
maybe its about my xml file i think its heavy or my code is need to be fixed.

here is my code

```
package ir.whitegate.guardians;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    getActionBar().hide();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstory);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Story.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            public void EXIT(View view) 
            {
                finish();
            }
        });

}
}
```

and here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/mainsithis">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toleft"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bios"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/howtoread"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/about"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/writer"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rateit"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:background="@drawable/moreapps"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toright"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="@drawable/rainbow"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.80">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonstory"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/starttoread"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/exit"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="EXIT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put error stack trace

Comment: can u show it in code please?

Comment: It's the error log that comes in logcat

Comment: thanks its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move EXIT method to class from button clicklistener.

Change addListenerOnButton method like below method

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

final Context context = this;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstory);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Story.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}

public void EXIT(View view) 
        {
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Story.class);
```

**to**

**Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Story.class);**

wrong parameter **context**

**Move this to buttonStory**
**`android:onClick="EXIT"`**

and **add the code to MainActivity**.

```
public void EXIT(View view) 
        {
            finish();
        }
```